Combining hand animation with a bezier circle walk cycle problems
I have been at this for over 24 hours but I cannot for the life of me work it out. I have an animated character (attached) that walks out from behind something, I've got it set and ready to start walking using a bezier circle placed beneath it that the legs will (in theory) follow the path of, using the Y axis to follow the back and forward motion, and Z to make the foot lift from the ground. I've seen all polyfjords videos relevant to this topic but he doesn't cover combining the walk cycle with manual animation. The IK bone snaps to the position of the bezier circle, and so does an empty (I thought I'd try using an empty that the IK bone is parented to).   In a polyfjord video he has it placed as such, and the Ik bone just follows the shape of the bezier circle rather than actually going to its location. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'll also attach the video so far so you can understand the context.
